# How to run commands in Docker after Vault is running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, hashicorp-vault

I have a Dockerfile which sets up Vault in Ubuntu with all required configurations. I now need to register a plugin and run a couple more commands. But all this has to be done while the vault server is running. For reference - https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021245994-Enabling-Oracle-Database-Secrets-Engine.
I need my image to come up running vault in dev mode, so I've tried `ENTRYPOINT vault server -dev` or `CMD vault server -dev`. However any command I try to run after this won't get executed.
If I had to do this manually I would usually

- Run the image which would come up with vault running
- Exec into the container from a different terminal and run my commands

However I want to automate the entire process in my Dockerfile. Things I have tried that don't work (I am trying to run `vault secrets enable database` after the vault server is running -

```
ENTRYPOINT vault server -dev
CMD vault secrets enable database
```

```
CMD vault server -dev; vault secrets enable database
```

```
CMD ["vault", "server", "-dev"]
CMD vault secrets enable database
```

Comment: You'd have to copy the shared libraries into the image.  But then you should be able to run the various `vault` commands from outside the container, setting `$VAULT_ADDR` to point at the (unsealed) Vault.  In general, a Docker container can't both run its main process and also set itself up after the process has started.

Comment: @DavidMaze so is it safe to say that it's not possible to automate the entire process just using docker and that I would indeed have to run those commands myself manually ?